# Harbor robot account: Error response from daemon: unauthorized: authentication required

Tags: docker, docker-registry, harbor

I'm always getting:

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://myregistry.example.com/v2/": unauthorized: authentication required
```

When trying to login with:

```
docker login --username robot$myproject+myrobotaccount myregistry.example.com
```

Answer (score 5):

**Quote** the robot username on **Linux**:

```
docker login --username 'robot$myproject+myrobotaccount' myregistry.example.com
```

But, do **NOT** quote the username on **Windows**

```
docker login --username robot$myproject+myrobotaccount myregistry.example.com
```

Comment: With newer Harbor versions  >2.2 I advise replacing the prefix containing the $ with something else like @ or _ to avoid  all possible problem with scripting and CI/CD where the $ (dollar sign) has a special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

don`n forget about special character - $

```
export DOCKER_USERNAME=robot\$myproject+myrobotaccount
export DOCKER_PASSWORD=sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfW
export CI_REGISTRY=myregistry.example.com

echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login "$CI_REGISTRY" --username $DOCKER_USERNAME --password-stdin
```